# How tall are the "fractured" linear structures on Europa's surface?

Tags: photography, europa, galileo-probe

What are the altitude differences in the high resolution part of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GjpQ.jpg) of Europa?

[image: Ridges on Europa]

How high do those ridges rise over their neighboring valleys? And how large is the area shown in this image?

And are the craters believed to have been formed by impacts or some kind of "eruptions" from below? It looks to me as if the areas which have the most (tiny) craters is on top of and thus newer than the less cratered areas. Well, here and there anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently they have been inferred to be "220 meters". See the references in:

S. D. Kadel, S. A. Fagents, "TROUGH-BOUNDING RIDGE PAIRS ON EUROPA", , Lunar and Planetary Science XXIX. ([PDF](http://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/LPSC98/pdf/1078.pdf))

Comment: I think that the text in your link says that they are on average 220 meters high, and that the ice layer under them is "kilometers to tens of kilometers" thick.